# Customise GlobalMessageConfig to remove messge on route change

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I am trying to implememt what looks like a very basic requirement in my Spartacus 4.3 where the cx-global-message goes away when user navigates to a new page.
I understand Spartacus provides a default timeout period depending on the message type. But is there a way to change it so that the message goes away, eighter if the user "x" out of it or if the user navigates to a different page.
Also is there a way to use globalMessageService.remove() to remove all notifications at one go.